# Powershell_Script with Guard Interpreter -> Action RUN everytime

Tags: chef-infra

Trying to just install dotnet 4.8 on windows server using below code:
Don't have any syntax errors, the problem is dotnet code gets installed, tried so many possibilities but the Guard `not_if` doesn't seem to work. I went through lot of examples on stacktrace and copy pasted to make sure something is not missed out. But nothing helped so far.

```ruby
powershell_script 'install_dotnet48' do
  guard_interpreter :powershell_script
  not_if "Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -name version -EA 0  | Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select Version | Where {$_.Version -match '4.8.0.3761'}"
  code "#{cache_path}\\#{node['dotnet48']['version']}\\Setup.exe"
  notifies :reboot_now, 'reboot[restart_server]', :immediately
end
```

Comment: reboot[restart_server] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
         * remote_file[C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache\48n.zip] action create_if_missing (skipped due to not_if)
         * powershell_script[extract_dotnet48] action run (skipped due to not_if)
         * powershell_script[install_dotnet48] action run

Comment: Is the `Version` you are matching `4.8.0.3761`, the same as what is returned? Or should it be: `4.8.03761` (notice the decimal position).

Comment: pretty certain the guard_interpreter for powershell_script should default to :powershell_script and you don't have to specify that.  if not, that's probably a bug in chef.

Answer (score 0):

The `not_if` guard in `powershell_script` resource is activated when the expression returns `true`.

> `not_if`
>
> Prevent a resource from executing when the condition returns `true`.

The command you are trying might not be returning `true` due to no matches for the `Version` string.

Perhaps you should try:

```
Where {$_.Version -match '4.8.03761'}
```

A better way to guard from installing .NET, might be to use the `creates` property, and point it to a file/path that would be created when .NET is installed. E.g.: `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET`

```ruby
powershell_script 'install_dotnet48' do
  code "#{cache_path}\\#{node['dotnet48']['version']}\\Setup.exe"
  creates 'C:/windows/Microsoft.NET'
  notifies :reboot_now, 'reboot[restart_server]', :immediately
end
```

This way the install will be idempotent and reported as `(up to date)` rather than `(skipped due to not_if)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. let me try this out. Its very nice and interesting point to learn :)